# 'CRDB Database unable to sync with member. Error connecting to member CRDB

Tags: redis

I am encountering an error message stating 'CRDB Database unable to sync with member. Error connecting to member CRDB' while using the CRDB syncer in Redis Enterprise. I have checked network connectivity, verified member status, and reviewed the configuration, but the problem persists.

I have checked network connectivity, verified member status, and reviewed the configuration, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Check that recently any Cipher or TLS related changes implemented in the cluster, can (--force) update the DB through crdb-cli, it will restart the syncer process.

Answer (score 0):

Issue : (Redis Enterprise) CRDB Database unable to sync with member.

During the investigation of an issue with the synchronization of a CRDB (Conflict-free Replicated Data Type) database in a Redis Enterprise active-active geo-distributed cluster, I meticulously reviewed the configuration and network settings, and extensively searched for potential solutions. Eventually, I delved into the log files of Redis Enterprise and found a crucial clue in the 'crdt_syncer-1.log' file.

The log indicated that the connection establishment was failing because Redis was appending a prefix to the provided DNS (Fully Qualified Domain Name). This prefix consists of the constant "redis-" followed by the endpoint number specified. If a port number like 12000 was specified, the FQDN would become "redis-12000.". Similarly, for port number 13000, the FQDN would be "redis-13000.".

To resolve this issue, it became apparent that we needed to add the DNS entry to the operating system's '/etc/hosts' file, associating the respective IP address with the DNS name. By doing so, the Redis Enterprise node could establish the necessary connections and overcome the synchronization problem.

This solution ensures that the Redis Enterprise cluster can effectively communicate with the CRDB member and successfully synchronize data, resolving the initial issue encountered.

https://link.medium.com/sF2cL3kPeBb

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/aditya-mishra-b947321a1_data-connections-like-activity-7081285082971279361-oK46?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_android

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).